# Cakephp 3.x retrieve user informations inside beforeFind

Tags: php, model, cakephp-3.0

As it is said in the documentation, I want to modify informations return by **find()** method using the **beforeFind()** callback.

> You might use this callback to restrict find operations based on a
>   user’s role, or make caching decisions based on the current load.

But I actually can't figure how to retrieve the user's informations inside the model. Ex :

```
public function beforeFind(\Cake\Event\Event $event, Query $query, $options, $primary) {
    $query->where(['society_id' => $user->society_id]);
}
```

Thank's for your time.

Comment: And by "_user_" you are referring to the current authenticated user?

Comment: Have you looked in to this [link](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers/components/authentication.html#accessing-the-logged-in-user)?

Comment: @ndm, yes, I mean the current user.

Comment: @Ray, the problem is that AuthComponent is not part of the model and I can't figure out how to load it. loadComponent() is not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way of getting the logged in user in your table callbacks is by using the Footprint plugin:

https://github.com/usemuffin/footprint

If you do a `debug($options)` in your `beforeFind()` you will see the user information there.